# Why neo4r fail to create a conncetion object?

Tags: r, neo4j

I am trying to use a r package neo4r conncet to neo4j.

From remote machine I am able to connect the browser at the URL

```
http://<my remote machine IP address>:7474/browser
```

However, I am fail to create a connection object with the following R code.

```
library(neo4r)
library(magrittr)
con <- neo4r::neo4j_api$new(
  url = "http://<my remote machine IP address>:7474",
  user = "neo4j",
  password = rstudioapi::askForPassword()
)

con$ping()
con$get_version()
```

Which gives me

```
> con$get_version()
NULL
> con$ping()
[1] 404
```

I expect to have a 200 return from `con$ping()`, 404 stands for the url problem.

I am not sure what is the problem results in the failure.

I hope someone could give me some hint about this.

Thank you!

---

Version information:

neo4j community edition 4.0.0

neo4j browser 4.0.1

neo4r 0.1.3

---

R session information

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C           LC_TIME=C.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=C.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=C.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=C.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=C.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C              LC_ADDRESS=C           LC_TELEPHONE=C        
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=C.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C   

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] magrittr_1.5 neo4r_0.1.3 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.3        compiler_3.6.2    pillar_1.4.3      later_1.0.0       tools_3.6.2       digest_0.6.24    
 [7] jsonlite_1.6.1    tibble_2.1.3      lifecycle_0.1.0   pkgconfig_2.0.3   rlang_0.4.4       shiny_1.4.0      
[13] cli_2.0.1         rstudioapi_0.11   curl_4.3          fastmap_1.0.1     httr_1.4.1        dplyr_0.8.4      
[19] vctrs_0.2.2       attempt_0.3.0     tidyselect_1.0.0  glue_1.3.1        data.table_1.12.8 R6_2.4.1         
[25] fansi_0.4.1       purrr_0.3.3       tidyr_1.0.2       promises_1.1.0    htmltools_0.4.0   assertthat_0.2.1 
[31] mime_0.9          xtable_1.8-4      httpuv_1.5.2      crayon_1.3.4
```

---

neo4j config file

```
#*****************************************************************
# Network connector configuration
#*****************************************************************

# With default configuration Neo4j only accepts local connections.
# To accept non-local connections, uncomment this line:
dbms.connectors.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0

# You can also choose a specific network interface, and configure a non-default
# port for each connector, by setting their individual listen_address.

# The address at which this server can be reached by its clients. This may be the server's IP address or DNS name, or
# it may be the address of a reverse proxy which sits in front of the server. This setting may be overridden for
# individual connectors below.
dbms.connectors.default_advertised_address=localhost

# You can also choose a specific advertised hostname or IP address, and
# configure an advertised port for each connector, by setting their
# individual advertised_address.

# By default, encryption is turned off.
# To turn on encryption, an ssl policy for the connector needs to be configured
# Read more in SSL policy section in this file for how to define a SSL policy.

# Bolt connector
dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true
#dbms.connector.bolt.tls_level=DISABLED
dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=:7687

# HTTP Connector. There can be zero or one HTTP connectors.
dbms.connector.http.enabled=true
dbms.connector.http.listen_address=:7474

# HTTPS Connector. There can be zero or one HTTPS connectors.
dbms.connector.https.enabled=false
dbms.connector.https.listen_address=:7473

# Number of Neo4j worker threads.
#dbms.threads.worker_count=
```

Answer (score 2):

The current version of Neo4j Driver for R is not again available for the version 4.0 of Neo4j.

You must use the version 3.5.19 of Neo4j.

Answer (score 1):

There is a github branch of Neo4R available which adds a flag for version 4.0 neo4j graphs

```
devtools::install_github("davidlrosenblum/neo4r@4.x")
con <- neo4j_api$new(
  url = "http://localhost:7474", 
  user = "neo4j", 
  password = "password",is_V4 = TRUE
)
```